# Hibernate entity lifecycle

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, lifecycle

I'm getting in trouble trying to separate the business and the persistance in my project.
The skeleton does more or less something like:

```
private UsuarioBO findById(String idUsuario) {
    Usuario dao = getUsuarioDao().findById(idUsuario);
    return new UsuarioBO(dao);
}

private void save(UsuarioBO bo){
    Usuario dao = bo.bo2dao();
    getUsuarioDao().save(dao);
}
```

Some clarifications about the code above:

- UsuarioBO is a business objet and Usuario is an entity mapped to a DB
  table.
- The `new UsuarioBO(dao)` is just a mapping method and the
  `bo.bo2dao()` is also a mapping method, but it creates a new empty entity
  Usuario.
- As you can see, the entity created in both methods is erased of memory on method finish.

The problem goes when i try to do this:

```
UsuarioBO example = findById("whatever");
save(example);
```

When i do this, hibernate tells me "there's an existing entity with the same identifier", and thats true! (It's creating an entity on `findById()` and another on `save()` ).

The only solution i've found is to use the entity as "bo". I mean, bring the entity object to the service, do whatever modifications on the entity directly, and when i finish do the save sending the entity in spite of a BO.

I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing so, but how?

**EDIT:**
this is the `save(dao)` method:

```
public void save(Usuario usuario) throws Exception {
    try {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(usuario);

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            //error treatment
    throw e;
    }
}
```

this is the `bo2dao()` method (its inside the BO bean):

```
public Usuario bo2dao() throws Exception {

    Usuario dao = new Usuario();

    try {

        dao.setId(this.id);
        dao.setPassword(this.password);
        //other similar fields...
        dao.setLastLoginTime(this.lastLoginTime);

        Role r = new Role();
        r.setId(LoginHelper.getRoleId(this.role.getName()));
        dao.setRole(r);

        Status s = new Status();
        s.setId(LoginHelper.getStatusId(this.status.getName()));
        dao.setStatus(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw e;
    }

    return dao;
}
```

In this case, `Role` and `Status` are also entity beans connected with `Usuario` (one user can only have one role and one status).

`getRoleId()` and `getStatusId()` returns the correspondent id from the name (for example: `"UNLOCKED"` returns `1`)

Comment: Hibernate tells you *there's an existing entity with the same identifier* as an ERROR message or as a WARN/INFO/DEBUG message?

Comment: What hibernate method is this calling `getUsuarioDao().save(dao)`? If it's calling the `save()` then it should be either `update()` (or `saveOrUpdate()`) instead. Because you are not inserting a new record, you are actually retrieving an existing one and updating it. If you try to do this with the `save()` method, hibernate will throw the error you mentioned.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza It's sending me as an ERROR, and the application crashes...

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung its calling saveOrUpdate(). I'll edit the first post with that info.

Comment: If that's not the case then it might this - `Usuario dao = bo.bo2dao()`, which might be creating a new instance but in the process also copying the id from the old one to the new one. Can you show exactly how it is creating and returning the new instance?

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung Of course! it's now edited. 

In spite of all, as you can see, always the life of the DAO in both methods, starts and ends inside the method.
oh! and you can see in the code above, the id that i'm getting with "findById", is the same as the "save". Thats why hibernate claims! :(

Comment: @lozan Why do you worry about life-circle when the hibernate tells you if the persistent object exist or is not then gives you error because you have chosen incorrect method to update the existent object.

Comment: @RomanC So you suggest me using "merge" instead of save//saveorupdate?

I'm just asking this, not looking for the solution code, but seeking for the best way of doing it. I mean, just for some ideas... How does the people usually do this?

Comment: Noone else can make me a suggestion? :(